# TFS Build Definition Post Deployment Scripts Error When Executing Scripts

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

I have a TFS Build definition using the default template.  The build completes on it's own but when I include a post deployment script I get the following error.

```
Exception Message: The directory name is invalid (type Win32Exception)
Exception Stack Trace: 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo     startInfo)
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.ProcessWrapper.    Start()
   at     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.InvokeProcessIn    ternal.RunCommand(AsyncState state)
   at     System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr     md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at     System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage     msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message     reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,     MessageData& msgData)
   at System.Func`2.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncC    odeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager     bookmarkManager)
```

The script itself is a powershell script that is included in the solution I'm trying to build and it only calls write-host messages.  (for testing at this point)

The build definition has all the defaults selected with only the solution, post build arguments and post build script path changed.  The script is checked into source control in the solution.

This is a POC environment so I have everything installed on the one server, so the TFS Server and Build Agents are on the same machine.

I've tried several workaround for this but none of them seem to be rooted around this particular error.  Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does the Process tab of the build process template look like? Did you specify the **source control** path to the script?

Comment: And if you've mapped the source control path correctly, have you included this in your source mappings to make sure the file is downloaded to your build server?

Comment: Thanks for the response @DanielMann.

In the ProcessTab I have under the default template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml) 2 Build -> 5.Advanced -> 
Post Build Script Arguments: -verbose
Post Build Script Path:  $/TeamProject/Dev/Solution/DeploymentScripts/PostBuildDeployment.ps1

In the Source Settings Tab:
Source control: $/TeamProject/Dev/Solution/DeploymentScripts/PostBuildDeployment.ps1 
Build Agent: C:\Projects\Dev\Solution\DeploymentScripts/PostBuildDeployment.ps1
Source control: $/TeamProject/Dev/Solution 
Build Agent: C:\Projects\Dev\Solution

Comment: @WouterKort refer to my previous comment for the source mapping, I have seen this downloaded to the build directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Coming from someone who recently encountered this issue themselves)

Check your "Source Settings" in the build definition.

- Make sure you haven't cloaked the path to your script. That is, if you have your script in `utilities/configuration`, make sure you haven't cloaked `utilities/`
- Your Build Agent folder should not use `$(BuildDir)`, it should use `$(SourceDir)`. Bear in mind this might change some paths in your script.

There is apparently a bug in the latest version of TFS that causes this hair-pulling issue. All the stuff about setting `%WINDIR%` in your Start-in directory for Powershell/Cmd etc. didn't work, but this did.

Comment: Fixed my problem too !!